# How to groupby and sum values in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get unique user names and their total time, but don't know how to achive this.
What I have already done is an array of unique names, but dont know how to get the sum.
I think this should be achived by using a structure like dictionary for ex. 
`Dictionary<string,int>` but this structure seems to not exists in typescript.

```js
let json = [{"User":"Tom Smith","Hours": 6},{"User":"Mark Zuckerberg","Hours": 8},{"User":"Elon Musk","Hours": 12},{"User":"Tom Smith","Hours": 1},{"User":"Tom Smith","Hours": 1}];

for(var i  = 0; i < json.length; i++)
{
    if(!userNames.find(a => a == json[i].User))
    {
        userNames.push(json[i].User);
    }
}
```

Result should be:

- Tom Smith → 8 Hours
- Mark Zuckerberg → 8 Hours
- Elon Musk → 12 Hours

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its called `Map`:

```
 const usernames = new Map<string, number>();

 for(const {User, Hours} of json) 
   usernames.set(User, (usernames.get(User) || 0) + Hours);

 console.log([...usernames]);
```

Comment: Wow, it is what I have been looking for!
This works, but I simplified structure of json for better readability.
What if structure is a little bit more complicated/nested?

Comment: It does not matter, I've found that all I have to do is pass the correct path in the for loop.
Thank you Jonas one more time!

Comment: @tylkonachwile glad to help :)